# Prevent PyCharm from overwriting PYTHONPATH in remote Docker interpreter

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I've set up a remote Docker interpreter in PyCharm 2019.2, where I'm able to connect and run a simple Python script just fine. However, the Docker image that I'm trying to use (`ros:kinetic-ros-base`) makes some modifications to `$PYTHONPATH` in its entrypoint, which it seems PyCharm ignores/overwrites.

I can demonstrate this by printing the `$PYTHONPATH` variable straight from the Docker container:

```
$ docker run -it ros:kinetic-ros-base python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
'/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
```

Or by using PyCharm to run a script via the remote Docker interpreter, using the same `ros:kinetic-ros-base` image:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

```
/opt/project:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display
```

Clearly PyCharm is replacing the `$PYTHONPATH` variable after the container's entrypoint script runs.

I can hack around this by adding `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to the run configuration's Environment Variables in `Edit Configurations...`, but then code inspections that rely on the container's PYTHONPATH fail to resolve. The line `import rospy` gives the IDE error `No module named rospy`, though it will run just fine (obviously, the PYTHONPATH is only set on Run in this case).

Is there any way to either

1. Get PyCharm to respect changes made to PYTHONPATH in the Docker image's ENTRYPOINT script, or
2. Get the integrated code editor inspections to use a manually defined PYTHONPATH environment variable in the Run configuration?

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with yours but without using docker. I am setting a PYTHONPATH as environment variable in the Run configuration. But Pycharm is adding is own path to my pythonpath and that break the script I want to use.